# symfony 404 error - problems with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, symfony, nginx

Opening `Symfony/web/app_dev.php` shows 404 file not found, trying to open other pages (except config page) again shows 404 file not found. I read that there is problems with mod rewrite.

This is my server configuration:

```
server {    
        listen   80;    
        listen   [::]:80;    
        root /home/user/Projects/stereoshoots/www;    
        server_name stereoshoots.local;    

        location / {    
                autoindex  on;    
#                try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;    
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;    
        }

#        location @rewrite {    
#                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;    
#        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|txt)$ {    
            access_log        off;    
            expires           30d;    
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {    
                return 204;    
                access_log     off;    
                log_not_found  off;    
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {    
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;    
                fastcgi_index index.php;    
                include fastcgi_params;    
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {    
                deny all;  
        }
}
```

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For a symfony2 app have a look at this sample config file to get the info you are looking for:
http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony

You want your server root to be in the web directory

```
root /home/user/Projects/stereoshoots/www/Symfony/web;
```

Then redirect all requests in there to the app.php

```
rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```